# How do iptables ports work?

Tags: iptables, proxy, http, port, https

Let's say, for instance, a user on the network makes a HTTP request to http://serverfault.com. I believe the destination port (dport) in this case is 80.

1. What is the source port (sport)?
2. If the user instead makes a request to https://serverfault.com (pretend that's a valid URL), I believe the dport is 443. Is that correct?
3. If the user has configured their browser to use a proxy server, is the dport still 80/443, or does it change to whatever port the proxy server is running on? What about the sport?
4. Does the dport/sport normally change as it traverses iptables chains/rules? What about in the case where the user is going through a proxy server?

Comment: Unfortunately you've combined several different, albeit related, questions all in the same question. Some of them are also fundamental topics for TCP/IP networking, which makes it hard to answer succinctly in a way that's acceptable for a StackExchange site. Have a gander at the [FAQ] to see what I mean. I think you'll get much better results to splitting these up.

Answer (score 3):

1. The source port is randomly selected by the OS from the range 1024-65535.
2. 443 is the well known port for HTTP over SSL/TLS (but as with HTTP you can do that on any port; the client just needs to know and address it explicitly).
3. (I am not familiar with proxies.) There are several common ports for proxies, e.g. 3128 and 8080.
4. Netfilter changes the headers only if it is told to do so. Addresses are only changed when NAT (network address translation) is used. If a proxy is used then you have one connection at the application layer but two on the transport layer: one from the client to the proxy and a second one from the proxy to the real target.

Comment: So netfilter (iptables) can change the headers of the packet, but only in the NAT table? Are the dport and sport part of the headers?

Comment: If you configure a proxy server on the workstation, there are two connections: one from the workstation to the proxy (on port 3128, 8080, or whatever), and one from the proxy to the world (on port 80, 443, or whatever).  (Source ports in both cases are irrelevant.)  This is different from transparent proxy, which can be done through configuring netfilter and squid appropriately (see http://www.shorewall.net/Shorewall_Squid_Usage.html#TPROXY for an example).

Comment: A typical (i.e. TCP/UDP) packet (on the wire - layer 2) has at least three headers: (1) the link layer header which addresses the NIC. (2) the IP header (which addresses the target; need not be an address of the receiving system if that is a router). (3) The TCP/UDP header. dport and sport are part of the TCP/UDP header. The feature is called "NAT" but the table name is `nat`. Other parts of the headers (e.g. the DSCP field) can be changed in other tables (`mangle` in this case).

Comment: @PaulGear In the case of a transparent proxy there are two separate TCP connections, too. The end point just isn't what the client expects it to be. But that doesn't change the fact that the connection ends at the proxy.

Comment: Good point. The port numbers are different, but not the number of connections.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. However, what I'd really like to know is how iptables sees the dport/sport (and if it changes) in relation to a proxy.